# How to disable/remove JSON native support in Oracle 12.2

Tags: json, oracle

I'm working on a Oracle 12.2 database and I want to turn it off/remove/disable the default JSON support.

The project I'm working on already had a JSON library for all the JSON interactions. My database has recently been updated from 12.1 to 12.2 and now the original JSON library will not compile anymore. After some searching I found that is has conflicts with default implementation of JSON in 12.2, and this didn't occur in 12.1. Some syntax is shared between the old library and the new JSON support.

It is gone be a lot of work to change all my old code to work with the new JSON support, so I would rather disable the JSON support and keep using my old library. But I was not able to find on the internet how do this.

Comment: No possible. You will have to migrate your existing code to work with Oracle 12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON support is native, eg it is part of the RDBMS 'C' code. It is not possible to remove it. Can you post the details of the library you were using and the conflicts so we can document them and make recommendations on how to migrate. It was introduced starting with 12.1.0.2.0 (which 12.1 version were you working with ?). Assuming your library is a set of PL/SQL functions you should be able to avoid conflicts by properly qualifying your function names with a schema, which might be less work than doing a full migration, however I would strongly recommend migrating to the native JSON support ASAP, as it is probably much more performant.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using multiple Orcale databservers and some are running on older versions of Orcale. If I decide to migrate to the native JSON I will need to have different projects, one compatible with the older version and one with the newer versions. And I also found of that the native JSON does not supply all the functions needed. So I quess I'm just gone rename everything in order to avoid the conflicts. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please identify which JSON package you are using, and what conflicts you have encountered.